# Disable Multiple failures in NUnit 3.10

Tags: assertions, nunit-3.0

I upgraded my NUnit to v3.10.1 and faced with an issue related to "Multiple assertions". All my tests started to show multiple failures that are not needed for me. I would like to fail a test with Assert.Fail().
I have a lot of try-catch blocks where I'm failing a test with Assert.Fail() method. And I really need it to be failed with this message and not to go to the next Assert and show multiple assert failures.
Sure, maybe it was not a good approach to implement it in such blocks but now I will have to refactor all the code that is hell...

Could you please advice, is there any way to disable the multiple assertions or what should be done to fail a test at once I need it and not continue to next assert?

Will appreciate your answers! Thank you in advance!